# Programming an Assistant in Python. Is it possible to use the SpeechRecognition in Pycharm with only keywords being detected?

Tags: python, input, output, speech-recognition

Here is a simple speech recognition program I am doing right now... I did import Speech recognition...

```
def takeCommand():
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:

    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)
    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Processing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
    print("User said: {query}\n")


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Inactivity detected")
    return "None"

return query
```

Example input and output would be...

```
if 'how are you' in query:
speak("I am fine, Thank you")
```

The question here is if I can make it listen for the whole sentence and pick up on one keyword that gives you the same output. In other words, different ways of putting the sentence "Solve this math equation" "Can you solve this math equation" "Solve this equation" The word "Solve" would be the keyword for the same output.

Is this possible to do with this library?

Comment: can you give complete code?

Comment: The usual format is Year-Month-Day. Since there are not 22 months, this probably explains the problem.

Comment: Try `print(aapl)` to see the full results.